# Python, how to average month from 15th to 15th of each month, or nth to nth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, average

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below with a datetime column and a value column

| timestamp | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 100 |
| 1/2/2023 | 90 |
| .... |  |
| 12/12/2023 | 85 |

i know how to group from month to month, but looking for something a bit more nuanced to calculate the average monthly value but from the 15th of one month to the 15th of the next month, looking something like below

| timestamp | mean_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/15/2023 - 2/15/2023 | 95 |
| 2/15/2023 - 3/15/2023 | 93 |
| .... |  |
| 11/15/2023 - 12/15/2023 | 84 |

I tried grouping from month to month and shifting a time column by 15, but this isnt exact since every month has a different amount of days..

Comment: I don't see a problem; shifting the date back by 15 days and groupby `Y/M` totally does what you want. You just need to mask the new time period correctly

Comment: "this isnt exact since every month has a different amount of days.." - subtracting 14 days should actually work fine, because your target periods differ in their number of days in exactly the same way that calendar months differ in their number of days. Jan 15th midnight -> Feb 15th midnight has 31 days. Feb 15th midnight -> Mar 15th midnight has 28 days... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe either of these should work:

```
(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.day.eq(15).cumsum(),as_index=False)
 .agg({'date':lambda x: '{} - {}'.format(*x.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').iloc[[0,-1]].tolist()),
       'value':'mean'}))
```

or

```
(df.groupby((df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta('14D')).dt.to_period('M'),as_index=False)
 .agg({'date':lambda x: '{} - {}'.format(*x.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').iloc[[0,-1]].tolist()),
       'value':'mean'}))
```

Comment: The first approach might not work if the data is not daily, e.g. stock price which only presents on business day.

Comment: yeah that's a really good point.